# How to commit everything without multiple clicking to mark all checkboxes?

Tags: svn, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for a big multi-module project. We use SVN for source control.
After I made a lot of changes (e.g. refactoring) I want to check them in all in one commit.
But when I press the commit button on the top toolbar, I see commit window with only one module selected, and I have to manually check all the modules:

[image: commit window]

The question is: how to check in all modules at once without this manual clicking?

Comment: If you'd like a button for this, please star this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-131191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more of a UI hack, but you can do it like this:

With the focus in the modules list pane, hit <kbd>Ctrl - a</kbd> to select everything and then hit <kbd>Space</kbd> to select / deselect all of the modules at once.

Otherwise, you could try to do this via the `Changes` pane (shortcut: <kbd>Alt - 9</kbd>) and use the `Commit Changes...` operation from there.